# Daily XML's download to webserver from fixed external URL's

Tags: php, xml, cron

I have multiple URL's which each points to a XML file, though it takes a few minutes  pointing to URL manually and waiting for each XML to be collected and saved to desktop.

Therefor I am looking for a script that could automatically visit the URL's (one by one) at night and download each XML to a folder on our Apache server.

So I think the following two codes are required:
1. PHP script to visit multiple defined URL's;
2. Cron script to run nightly above point-1.

I can't seem to find anything relevant on the net, so my hope is with you. 
I'd like to thank you in advance for taking the effort and time.

Kind regards,
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SimpleCrawler {
    private $url;
    private $data; 
    public function __construct($url){
         $this->url = $url;
         $this->load();
    }

    public function load(){
        $this->data = file_get_contents($this->url);
    }

    public function getData(){
       return $this->data;
    }


}
```

File class:

```
Class File {
     protected static $instance;
     protected $isResource = false;
     public $item;

     public static function getInstance(){
         if(!self::$instance){
             self::$instance = new self();
         }

         return self::$instance;
     }

     public function setResource($flag){
          $this->isResource = $flag;
     }
     public static function fromFile($path){
         $obj = self::getInstance();
         $obj->item = $path;

         return $obj;
     }

     public static function fromSource($string){
         $obj = self::getInstance();
         $obj->item = $string;
         $obj->setResource(true);

         return $obj;
     }

     public function save($path){

       try {
        if($this->isResource){
            $fopen = fopen($path,'w');

            fwrite($fopen,$this->item);
        }
        else {
             copy($this->item,$path);
        }

       }
       Catch(Exception $e){
          throw $e;
       }
     }
}
```

And how to use it:

```
$getXML = new SimpleCrawler('http://mydomain.com/file.xml');
$xmlString = $getXML->getData();

$file = File::fromSource($xmlString);
$file->save("/my/writtable/path/file.xml");
```

I hope this helps..

Warning: I write it from mind, it's not tested.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML scripts don't need authentication, you can do this with a simple shell script and either wget or curl to download the files

```
wget -O /local/path/myfile.xml http://example.com/myfile.xml
```

or

```
curl -o /local/path/myfile.xml http://example.com/myfile.xml
```