# Daily download of an external hosted and password protected xml file to our webserver - http

Tags: php, xml, http

This is basicly the same questions as the following, but in our case the source is password protected (username and password)

[Daily XML's download to webserver from fixed external URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001745/daily-xmls-download-to-webserver-from-fixed-external-urls)

Is this possible through http?

How to code this stuff?

Answer (score -1):

What type of authentication is required? If there is Basic Authentication with Apache then you can automatically login by writing the URL in this way:

http://user:password@host.com/file.xml

simple php example:

```
<?php 
$content = file_get_contents('http://user:password@host.com/file.xml');
?>
```